# Custom route for user/admin logins

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, routes

I have a platform built in Ruby on Rails that supports creation of websites with their own content, users etc. I want this route to show the sign in page for devise:

```
devise_scope :user do
  get '/websites/:website_id/users/sign_in' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :website_session end
```

I get error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"websites", :locale=>:en, :id=>nil}
```

My resources are set up in the routes file as below. What should I change?

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "devise/custom/registrations", :sessions => "devise/custom/sessions"}

resources :websites do
  resources :users end
```